# how to use ancal in android appiication?

Tags: android

i have to make an android application with a calender control in it? i want to use ancal for this purpose.

How do i use ancal within my application. There are .apk's available for android of Ancal, should i download them? But if i do download them then how do i integrate that apk with my android application.

If not the above then what is the other way of using ancal in my application.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to 'integrate' elements from some .apk into another. However, [ancal is open source](http://code.google.com/p/ancal/) so you could just grab the source and integrate it into your project.

Comment: that is what i am asking, how to integrate? 
F

Comment: import the source code from the ancal project into your own project. you can find the source code here http://code.google.com/p/ancal/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

i think you want these but i really don't know if it support integration i would sugest you ask them. 
http://vetch.magot.pl/pages/download.html

Hope it helped